# Was the only purpose of the $\log$ function to express the inverse of the exponential function in function form?

Tags: logarithms, math-history

Note: My $2$ main questions are in bold.

Why essentially was the $\log$ function was created? To answer this question, I asked myself, what would be the inverse of the function $y=2^x$. The inverse would be $x=2^y$, but why was $\log$ used for isolation of the variable $y$? **Was the initial sole purpose of the $\log$ function to express such an equation in in function form?**

For instance, with the equation $x=2^y$, why couldn't people just find $f(2)$ as $2=2^y$, and thus figure out the value of $f(1)=1$? Why did they need to create a whole new $\log$ function to express this in terms of $y$, when finding a table of values was just as easy, or even easier than creating a whole new function?

**If there were any purposes of the $\log$ function *that could not be achieved with normal exponents*, what were they?**

Comment: Probably a more on-topic question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ,although there might be equally good experts on this site as well.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thanks for the tip!

Comment: See related posts: [is the symbol $e$ for the base of natural logarithm honoring Euler](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3861/is-the-symbol-e-for-the-base-of-natural-logarithm-honoring-euler) and [which-came-first-the-natural-logarithm-or-the-base-of-the-natural-logarithm](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/42/which-came-first-the-natural-logarithm-or-the-base-of-the-natural-logarithm).

Comment: $x = 2^y$ is _not_ the inverse of $y=2^x$. Its inverse is some other function, which is called log.

Comment: @olivier $x=2^y$ is the inverse, it is just not in function form. That is what my whole question is based off of.

Comment: You're not using consistent notations. If $y =2^x$, then $x =\log(y)$. Here you swapped $x$ and $y$ in the second equation so that $y$ becomes the dependent variable, which leads to some confusion. I guess this is how they taught you to inverse functions, however.

Comment: I know what $\log$ is, I am asking why it was created to isolate $y$, as isolating $y$ was not much use but to make the equation in function format.

Answer (score 3):

[Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#History) was invented around 1600 by [John Napier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier) to simplify difficult calculations: a multiplication can be reduced to addition.

It was very useful in the computation of astronomical tables.

See the quote from Laplace, who called logarithms

> "[a]n admirable artifice which, by reducing to a few days the labour of many months, doubles the life of the astronomer, and spares him the errors and disgust inseparable from long calculations."

Comment: I am interested on how $\log$ was more beneficial than normal exponents during that time. Did astronomical tables require $\log$?

Comment: @YashJain astronomical tables needed multiplication, and multiplication became much easier with logarithms (especially with Henry Briggs's base-$10$ logarithms).

Answer (score 2):

While the logarithmic function is obviously the inverse of the exponential function it's main purpose is to convert large numbers to smaller numbers.

For example for $$x=100,000,000,$$

$$ log(x)= 8.$$

From $$log(xy)=log (x) + log (y)$$ we get $$log(3600) = 2+log(36)=2+2(log2 +log3)$$
Applications such as Earthquake Richter's scale or Radioactive half life makes logarithms a good tool to be around.

Logarithmic differentiation is used to find derivative of functions such as $$f(x)= x^x$$ and$$ f(x) = x^{sin x}.$$